# EXCEL VBA : Button to activate the drawing of an autoshape

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck. I've searched high and low, far and wide. And I cannot find a solution out there.

Is it possible to activate the line tool in the AutoShapes object via a Form Control button?

I know how to draw a line from fixed locations via a macro however I would like the user to draw their own lines.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 88.8, 447.6, 168.6, 480.6 _
    ).Select
```

Is there a way to activate the drawing tool but not actually draw it and allowing the user to complete the rest of the process themselves?

Thank you in advance,

Teebee

Comment: Good one... there doesn't appear to be a `CommandBarButton` for it. Might have been possible pre-2007.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-2007, everything was a `CommandBarButton`, with an `ID`. You get ahold of that `CommandBarButton`, you can invoke its `Execute` method.

Office 2007 ditched the commandbars and introduced the Ribbon. Some commandbars are still available and you *can* invoke them like in the old days, but as far as I can see there's no `CommandBarButton` remotely related to "shapes" or "connector".

I'm using this method:

```
Public Sub FindCmdBarControl(ByVal name As String)
    Dim cmdbar As CommandBar
    For Each cmdbar In Application.CommandBars
        Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl
        For Each ctrl In cmdbar.Controls
            If ctrl.TooltipText Like "*" & name & "*" Or ctrl.Caption Like "*" & name & "*" Then
                Debug.Print cmdbar.name, ctrl.Caption, ctrl.TooltipText, ctrl.ID
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

...but running `FindCmdBarControl "line"` yields this output:

```
Formatting    &Underline    &Underline (Ctrl+U)          115 
Cell          Sp&arklines                  31623 
Series        Add T&rendline...           Add T&rendline...            914 
Format Data Series          Add T&rendline...           Add T&rendline...            914 
List Range Popup            Sp&arklines                  31623 
Nil           &Line         Insert Line Sparkline        18927 
Nil           &Column       Insert Column Sparkline      18928 
Nil           &Win/Loss     Insert Win/Loss Sparkline    18929 
Nil           Edit &Single Sparkline's Data...          Edit &Single Sparkline's Data...           19223 
Nil           &Group        Group Selected Sparklines    19226 
Nil           &Ungroup      Ungroup Selected Sparklines  19227 
Nil           &Clear Selected Sparklines  &Clear Selected Sparklines   19229 
Nil           C&lear Selected Sparkline Groups          C&lear Selected Sparkline Groups           19230 
Nil           &Hidden && Empty Cells...   Sparkline Hidden && Empty Cells            19224 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline Colors        19451 
Nil           Custom &Weight...           Sparkline Custom Weight      19453 
Nil           &Line         Convert to Line Sparkline    20450 
Nil           &Column       Convert to Column Sparkline  20451 
Nil           &Win/Loss     Convert to Win/Loss Sparkline              20452 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline Negative Point Colors       20473 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline Marker Colors               20474 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline High Point Colors           20475 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline Low Point Colors            20476 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline First Point Colors          20477 
Nil           &More Colors...             More Sparkline Last Point Colors           20478 
Line Color    &More Outline Colors...     &More Outline Colors...      1052 
Built-in Menus              &Group and Outline                         30032
```

So, say you want to invoke the `&Underline` command (ID 115), you can do this:

```
Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=115).Execute
```

Running `FindCmdBarControl "connector"` yields nothing, and I'm out of ideas. See if you can locate a command ID for what you're looking for... that said, there's already a built-in button in the Ribbon that does exactly what you want (let the user draw a connector)...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response. I've managed to find the ID within Connectors.

```
Application.CommandBars("Connectors").FindControl(ID:=1042).Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to point the right ID:

Commandbar = "Drawing"

Controlname= "&Line"

ID = 130